# QT Serial port communication for Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, qml, cross-platform

I am working on a QT cross-platform application which is about getting a data(commonly weight) from precision balance and to display it on the connected (target)device.

**FOR Windows PC**

Using  I can get the list of connected ports and I am able to get the data.

**FOR Android**

- The same code is not working
- How to access the port?
- Is there any 3rd party library available?

**Note:** Connection is done with RS232 to USB for PC(windows)

RS232 to OTG for mobile devices.

Comment: Seems support is partial. Take a look to [this page](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Serial_Port#QSerialPort) and the related links.